# How do I run a site from a sub-directory?

Tags: 8, installation, uri

I want to serve my Drupal site which is installed on example.com/drupal from example.com.

This particular site is an add-on site on my shared host, so the actual file structure is public_html/example.com/drupal.

What should I do, change the *.htaccess* file or add a redirect from cPanel?

I can't imagine I'm doing anything radical, but I did not find any clear-cut answer.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? accessing example.com/drupal should basically just work.

Comment: Right, I can access example.com/drupal.  I want to serve my site from example.com.  There seems to be a lot of widely varying information on how to achieve this on the Drupal.org forums  - mostly involving modifying $baseurl in settings.php, which doesn't seem to be a valid solution, actually.  Wouldn't a redirect in .htaccess be the preferred method?  My question here is an attempt not only to help myself, but also preserve the best response for the rest of the Drupal community.

Comment: Yes, the .htaccess is OK if that's what you want. But I'm not really sure why you put drupal in a sub-folder when example.com should serve Drupal and only Drupal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On an Apache server, adding the following lines to the  *.htaccess* file should help.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !drupal/
  RewriteRule (.*) /drupal/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Those lines have not been fully tested. Use them at your risk.