# Running a site from a sub-directory of the web root

Tags: 8, .htaccess, composer

I have a shared hosting account that I would like to set up a Drupal 8 website on. However, been the primary domain for the hosting account, I cannot change the hosting directory where CPanel serves-up the web content. I can install Drupal 8 in a sub-directory off the web-root, however, I would prefer the sub-directory portion not be shown in the URL (i.e. http://domain.com instead of http://domain.com/subdir). I have incorporated drupal-composer/drupal-project into my project.

Does anyone have a working .htaccess file that resolves this scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run Drupal 8 in a subdirectory?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/241761/how-do-i-run-drupal-8-in-a-subdirectory)

Comment: Answer partly resolves issue. However, now I have an issue with the admin/menu system showing the full path (not the redirected path). Obviously when clicking on those links, I get an 'access denied' error. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: If you want to run Drupal on www.example.com you need to install it in the root directory of your server OR point your domain to the subdirectory of your Drupal install.

Comment: @Tom Thorp, that is a new separate question. See if it already has been asked before, and if not, ask it yourself. You can provide a link to this question for reference.